# three.js Get objects relative this value on click (objects are all in an array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

### The Problem

Ok, so I'm relatively new with `three.js` and I'm trying to do this:  on click of a avatar in 3D space, it grabs the selected avatars relative this value (so I can do returned_object.position.x and returned_object.data.name, etc...) but it's not working.  Right now I can click an object, and it brings up the `three.js` SCENE values for the object, but not mine.

-- edit additions

I'd like to be able to grab the value of `this.data` set by the avatar function - on click of an avatar.
But when I `console.log(intersects);` as shown below in the code, it comes up with the three.js object, stuff.  [See this link for a screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/7gdy6160r/Capture.jpg)

I want to just do something like `console.log(intersects.data);` and have it return what is set in the avatar function

Sorry, this is surprisingly hard to put into words.

### The Code

Here's all the code that's needed to make sense of it all:

```
var avatars = [],
        avatar;

avatar = function(id, row) {

    this.data = row;

    this.avatar = new THREE.Object3D();
    this.avatar.add(head);
    this.avatar.position.x = 20 * id;
    //extra

    SCENE.add(this.avatar);

    avatars[id] = this;
}

$(document).click(function(event){
    // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1; 

    mouse.fx = -mouse.y / 6;
    mouse.fy = (mouse.x / 6) + 0.3;


    CAMERA.rotation.x = ((-mouse.y) / 30) + -0.4;
    CAMERA.position.z = (mouse.y * -20) + 80;
    CAMERA.position.x = (mouse.x * 20);

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, CAMERA );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( SCENE.children, true ); // It grabs all the objects in the scene, but I only need it to grab objects in the avatars array.

    console.log(intersects);

    //I want to just do - console.log(intersects.data); - and have it return what is set in the avatar function.
    console.log(intersects);


});
```

Comment: What do you mean with `SCENE values for the object`? Did you look at `intersects[0].object`? That's the object that was hit first by the raycaster and usually wants to be selected on mouse click. BTW: what kind of weird stuff you are doing with your camera position and rotation?

Comment: Just added more to the post to explain more; also, the "weird stuff' I'm doing with the camera position and rotation is simply for navigating over a small area. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I got it: Your avatar consists of a head or several objects and of course these objects are returned by the raycaster, but the data of interest is within your avatars array.

You could do it either way: Every `Object3D` has an `userData` object, where you can put your data (`this.avatar.userData = row;`). Since the intersect object is (in this case) the head which is a child object of your avatar, you access the data via `intersects[0].object.parent.userData`.

Maybe a better way would be to store just the id within that `userData` object. Because with the id you have an "reference" to the avatars array.

```
// save id to userData
this.avatar.userData.id = id;

// accessing avatar
var clickedAvatar = avatars[intersects[0].object.parent.userData.id];
console.log(clickedAvatar.data.name);
```